# Regular expression with php

Tags: php, regex

```
 $pattern="/[a-z]*[a-z]*/i";
if(!preg_match($pattern, $value)){
         $this->error_name="The name should contain at least two letters."; 
       }
```

I am trying to check if the user types his name with at least two letters. So basically, he cant enter his name as such 111111111111.. it must have two letters.

The regular expression that I wrote doesnt work..why?

Comment: Because `*` means "zero or more". `111111` has zero letters, so it matches. http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pattern="/[a-z].*[a-z]/i";
if(!preg_match($pattern, $value)){
   $this->error_name="The name should contain at least two letters."; 
}
```

Your code didn't work because `*` means zero or more times, so it would also match none or one character.

Comment: `.*` is not necessary if you only want to test whether the string contains two letters.

Comment: It only works like this : aa1111111111.. but what if the user name is a1111111111a.. it is also valid

Comment: Fixed by adding `.*` in between.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$pattern="/^[a-z]{2,}$/i";
```

This will ensure that the name has only letters and there are at least 2 letters in the name.

Edit:

Looks like you want the name to contain at least two letter and can contain other non-letters as well:

```
$pattern="/^.*[a-z].*[a-z].*$/i";
```

Comment: But it could also contain characters other than ``alpha``.

Comment: But I think that it means that , at least two letters starting close to another... this user name is also valid  a111111111b

Answer (score 1):

**Try this (your code modified):**

```
$pattern="/^[a-z]{2}.*/i";
if(!preg_match($pattern, $value)){
         $this->error_name="The name should contain at least two letters."; 
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Returns true when at least two alphabets are used in a string:

```
preg_match_all('/[a-z]/', $str, $m) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern="/^([a-z]{2})|([a-z].*[0-9].*[a-z].*).*/i";
```

I think the answer should be the one above.. your answers gave me a clue..

now it will match also those names:

a1111111111111a